# Java / Scala vs Linux native for non blocking (http) io

Tags: java, linux, scala, http, nonblocking

**So how do the facilities compare for using Linux native to Java /Scala for writing non blocking io?** At the time of writing I'm just learning about / playing around with writing an Http Server. So apologies up front if I have some basic gaps in my knowledge. Its currently all written in Scala using stream io. If I use native code for the system calls then obviously I've got to communicate between native C /C++ and my Scala code. I have done a bit of JNI before and I'm also interested in experimenting with running native code in a separate process.

However I want to emphasise **my question is not about Scala / Java native interface**, but purely about the advantages if any of using native system calls library over the Scala / Java ecosystem for Http serving. If using native I can use up to date kernels. In some ways this question is about learning, whether to invest my learning time in the Linux ecosystem or in the Java /Scala io and non blocking io ecosystem. I'm aware that there is a move to shunt TCP into userspace which could offer interesting possibilities.

I'm initially focussed on TCP/IP server, which is no doubt a primary use case, but also other io such as database access.

**Edit To expand:** Is java.nio fully asynchronous or does it actually use a form of polling behind the scenes? Is it possible to get full asynchronous using native or you always dependant on some form of polling? Does java.nio fully use the modern Kernel's asynchronous io facilities? My question is also stimulated by this article: [Streaming video on 10 Gigabit Ethernet and beyond](http://www.bbc.co.uk/rd/blog/2015/10/streaming-video-on-10-gigabit-ethernet-and-beyond) questioning the use of conventional sockets.

Comment: It might even cost more, transferring the data from/to the native side. As non-blocking I/O (with time-outs) is possible too on the JVM side. Try it out after you have made your first server in Scala/Java.

Answer (score 2):

For Http serving?  I'd say there really aren't any advantages.

Networking was baked into Java from the beginning, it was originally envisioned for use in set-top boxes and embedded devices.  With later generations, you have full support for non-blocking IO via the NIO APIs.

All of it will delegate to whatever IP stack your kernel provides, it works just fine on bleeding-edge kernels.

Scala runs on top of the JVM and gets all of this, for free.

Possibly the *only* use-case for breaking out to native code with networking is if you want to play with experimental transport protocols, or use one of the 3rd party SCTP implementations for windows.  None of this applies to HTTP + TCP.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your project requirements. If you have limited machine resources, either because you are starting out small with only a limited amount of horsepower under the hood or because you are going to get very big and you don't want to see you costs go up faster than your income, then programming closer to the hardware becomes very important.

The cost of programming so close to the hardware is substantially increased development costs. There have been advances in support for this level of programming: [Seastar](http://www.seastar-project.org/) is a newer library that claims to offer the kind of capability you asking for.

On the other hand, Scala with Akka IO is extremely performant. It allows you to write concise code that clearly does the job that you need without throwing data across boundaries.

It really comes down to this: are you optimizing your design before you know the real costs of your implementation? See [this stackoverflow conversation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil).